# having trouble with circular array and large image displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a little banner ad test and can't seem to figure out how to fix the way the main image is displaying in accordance with the thumbnails due to the code I put in specifically on the right thumbnail--I posted it here:
[view code here](http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/hotelstest.html)

I also need to change the text-and prices dynamically--if someone could show me a quick how-to  I'd be eternally grateful...

Ideally, I'd like the images to slide over when the arrows are pressed, but that may be asking for too much....

Thanks,
---Yvette

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hotels ad</title>
    <link href="mainstyleshotels2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

     <script>
    function init(){
    //document.getElementById("mainphoto").body.style.backgroundImage="url('i,ages/mainphoto0.jpg')";   

    }
    function init2(){
        ss_el = document.getElementById("ss_el");
        ss_elr = document.getElementById("ss_elr");
        ssSlide();
    }
        var ss_i=0;
        var ss_array=["<img src='images/paris_sm.jpg'/>",
                      "<img src='images/madrid_sm.png'/>",
                      "<img src='images/tokyo_sm.jpg'/>",
                      "<img src='images/amsterdam_sm.jpg'/>",
        ];
        var ss_el;
        var ss_elr;
        function ssNext(){
            ss_i++;
            if(ss_i > (ss_array.length - 1)){
                ss_i = 0;
            }
    ssSlide();
}
        function ssPrev(){
            ss_i--;
            if(ss_i < 0){
                ss_i = ss_array.length - 1;
            }
    ssSlide();
}
        function ssSlide(){
    ss_el.innerHTML = ss_array[ss_i];

    if(ss_i < (ss_array.length - 1)){
        ss_elr.innerHTML = ss_array[(ss_i)+1];
    }else{
        ss_elr.innerHTML = ss_array[0];
    }
    var urlString = 'url(images/mainphoto' + ss_i + '.jpg)';
    var obj= document.getElementById("mainphoto");
    obj.style.background =  urlString;
    //document.getElementById("mainphoto").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/mainphoto" + ss_i + ".jpg')";
    console.log(urlString);
}
     </script>
     </head>

     <body onLoad="init();init2();">
     <div id="wrapper">

     <div id="background"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
     <div id="black"><p id="para1">Hotel Hospes</p><p2 id="para2">Madrid, Spain</p2><p3 id="para3">$289</p3><p4 id="para4">$242</p4> </div>

     <div id="mainphoto"></div>
     <nav id="leftnav"><img src="images/goleft.png" width="27" height="28"/></nav>


    <nav id="rightnav" ><img src="images/goright.png" width="27" height="28" /></nav>
    <div id="ss_el"></div><div id="ss_elr"></div>

    <div id="cta"><img src="images/cta.png" width="170" height="56" alt="" /></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var goleft = document.getElementById("leftnav");
        goleft.addEventListener("click", changeMainImagesLeft, false);
        function changeMainImagesLeft(){
        ss_el = document.getElementById("ss_el");
        ss_elr = document.getElementById("ss_elr");
            ssNext();
        }       
        var goright = document.getElementById("rightnav");
        goright.addEventListener("click", changeMainImagesRight, false);    
        function changeMainImagesRight(){
            ss_el = document.getElementById("ss_el");
            ssPrev();
        }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>

   @charset "utf-8";
   /* CSS Document */
   body{
   height:480px
   width:320px; 
   }


     #background {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(images/backgroundt.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    height: 480px;
    width: 320px;
    }

    #black {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    background-color: #333333;
    top: 258px;
     }
     #cta {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 415px;
    margin-left: 147px;
    z-index: 1;

    }
    #cta:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
    }
    #ss_el {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 480px;
    padding-top: 0px;


    }
    #ss_elr {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 480px;
    margin-left: 160px;

   }
   #mainphoto {
    background:url(images/mainphoto0.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 149px;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    }

    #black p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top: -20px;
    left: 11px;
    }
    #black p2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    left: 12px;
    }
    #black p3 {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    left: 16px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    #black p4 {
    color: #EE2E33;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 86px;
    left: 15px;
    }
    #leftnav {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 529px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    }
    #leftnav:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
    }
    #rightnav {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 529px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 281px;
    padding: 3px;
    }
    #rightnav:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
    }

    #wrapper {
    left: 301px;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Your code link don't work

Comment: http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/hotelstest.html

Comment: I see an advert but not code.

Comment: hmm, both links work when I click them--but this is the url:http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/hotelstest.html

Comment: Post your code, directly into the question and preferably accompanied by a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) Your latest link also gives an advert.

Comment: What is it that needs to be fixed with the ad's main image?

Comment: I posted it here too:http://www.kamiblue.com/hotelstest/hotelstest.html

Comment: Are you on commission for spreading the advert? Post the code into the question.

Comment: well, when you press the arrows the main image should be the same as the thumbnail behind the arrow--the left arrow almost works, but the right doesnt work correctly at all...

Comment: no, not on commission and I'm not sure what advert is showing up--should be hotels.com--but I am not on commission--just trying to figure out how to do an advert like this

Comment: Post your code into the question and add specifically what the problem is that you are having with the code. Your title says `having trouble with circular array and large image displayed`, what array, where is it circular?

Comment: ss_array --it's circular as I have it reset on the ssNext and ssPrev functions when it reaches its limits--the problem is the main image should be in accord with the thumbnails under the arrows at the bottom of the faux advert..

Comment: You are trying to say that you want to access the data as a circular buffer, like it was joined end-to.end, correct?

Comment: yes and no:)-- I am just having difficulties with the array corresponding that moves the thumbnails corresponding to the main image--the ss_i variable ..chiefly, in writing to the DOM I am adding 1 to it on the right arrow so that either arrow can be used

Comment: please be clear what you want, there is only 2 thumbnail images. You want to display large image on click of next or prev button and on same time you want to change thumbnails on same click event.

Comment: So what is the problem that you are having with `ss_i` it is just contains a number? It looks fine to me.

Comment: the problem is when you press the right arrow and the hotel thumbnail changes the main image changes too, but it isnt matching up to the image in the right thumbnail --the left arrow doesnt work correctly either..but it is just a little bit off--the thumbnail under both arrows should be the same as the large image--say the hotel in amsterdam is showing up under the right arrow, I would need it to show up as the main image too as it is now selected by the arrows buttons...

Comment: the navigation is the thumbnails which loop--the problem is when you press either arrow and get a new thumbnail under that arrow the main image isn't the same as the thumbnail

Comment: If you click on either right or left arrow thumbnail will change and on next page how will you decide which one will be large image as there are 2 thumbnail?

Comment: You didn't get my point suppose if you have 3 thumbnails it is easy to select which one will be large image as we select centre thumbnail as large image on either left or right arrow click which change large image as well as thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Example

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:320px;
    height:480px;
}
#background {
    background-color:#e8e8de;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
#logo, #main, #mainphoto, #black, #nav, #previous, #current, #next {
    width:100%;
}
#logo {
    background: url(http://www.kamiblue.com/hotelstest/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    height:49px;
}
#main {
    height:320px;
}
#mainphoto {
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
#black {
    position:absolute;
    height:120px;
    -webkit-border-radius:13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius:13px 13px 13px 13px;
    border-radius:13px 13px 13px 13px;
    background-color:#333333;
    bottom:80px;
}
#paras {
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#para1, #para4 {
    font-size:1.5em;
}
#para3 {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
#para4 {
    color:#EE2E33;
}
#bookNow {
    position:absolute;
    background: url(http://www.kamiblue.com/hotelstest/images/cta.png) no-repeat;
    width:170px;
    height:56px;
    bottom:5px;
    right:2px;
}
#bookNow:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#previousWrap, #currentWrap, #nextWrap {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
}
#previous, #current, #next {
    height:110px;
}
#leftnav {
    position:absolute;
    background: url(http://www.kamiblue.com/hotelstest/images/goleft2.png) no-repeat;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:44px;
    height:44px;
}
#leftnav:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#rightnav {
    position:absolute;
    background: url(http://www.kamiblue.com/hotelstest/images/goright2.png) no-repeat;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:44px;
    height:44px;
}
#rightnav:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="background">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <img id="mainphoto"></img>
            <div id="black">
                <div id="paras">
                    <div id="para1"></div>
                    <div id="para2"></div>
                    <div id="para3"></div>
                    <div id="para4"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="bookNow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="leftnav"></div>
            <div id="rightnav"></div>
            <div id="previousWrap">
                <img id="previous"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="currentWrap">
                <img id="current"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="nextWrap">
                <img id="next"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function RingArray(object, position) {
    this.array = RingArray.compact(object);
    this.setPosition(position);
}

RingArray.toInt32 = function (number) {
    return number >> 0;
};

RingArray.toUint32 = function (number) {
    return number >>> 0;
};

RingArray.isOdd = function (number) {
    return number % 2 === 1;
};

RingArray.indexWrap = function (index, length) {
    index = RingArray.toInt32(index);
    length = RingArray.toUint32(length);
    if (index < 0 && RingArray.isOdd(length)) {
        index -= 1;
    }

    return RingArray.toUint32(index) % length;
};

RingArray.compact = (function (filter) {
    var compact;

    if (typeof filter === 'function') {
        compact = function (object) {
            return filter.call(object, function (element) {
                return element;
            });
        };
    } else {
        compact = function (object) {
            object = Object(object);
            var array = [],
                length = RingArray.toUint32(object.length),
                index;

            for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
                if (index in object) {
                    array.push(object[index]);
                }
            }

            return array;
        };
    }

    return compact;
}(Array.prototype.filter));

RingArray.prototype = {
    setPosition: function (position) {
        this.position = RingArray.indexWrap(position, this.array.length);

        return this;
    },

    setToStart: function () {
        return this.setPosition(0);
    },

    setToEnd: function () {
        return this.setPosition(this.array.length - 1);
    },

    setRandom: function () {
        return this.setPosition(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array.length));
    },

    increment: function (amount) {
        return this.setPosition(this.position + (RingArray.toInt32(amount) || 1));
    },

    previousElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position - 1, this.array.length)];
    },

    currentElement: function () {
        return this.array[this.position];
    },

    nextElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position + 1, this.array.length)];
    }
};

var mainphoto = document.getElementById('mainphoto'),
    previous = document.getElementById('previous'),
    current = document.getElementById('current'),
    next = document.getElementById('next'),
    para1 = document.getElementById("para1"),
    para2 = document.getElementById("para2"),
    para3 = document.getElementById("para3"),
    para4 = document.getElementById("para4"),
    offers = [{
        url: "http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/images/mainphoto0.jpg",
        name: 'Hotel Hospes',
        location: 'Madrid, Spain',
        price: '$289',
        offer: '$242'
    }, {
        url: "http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/images/mainphoto1.jpg",
        name: 'Hotel Godard',
        location: 'Paris, France',
        price: '$1200',
        offer: '$1099'
    }, {
        url: "http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/images/mainphoto2.jpg",
        name: 'Park Hyatt',
        location: 'Tokyo, Japan',
        price: '$1500',
        offer: '$1399'
    }, {
        url: "http://www.liferingart.com/hoteltest/images/mainphoto3.jpg",
        name: 'Hotel Citadel',
        location: 'Amsterdam, The Netherlands',
        price: '$180',
        offer: '$157'
    }],
    offersRing = new RingArray(offers);

function update(x) {
    var currentOffer = offersRing.currentElement();

    mainphoto.src = current.src = currentOffer.url;
    para1.textContent = currentOffer.name;
    para2.textContent = currentOffer.location;
    para3.textContent = currentOffer.price;
    para4.textContent = currentOffer.offer;

    previous.src = offersRing.previousElement().url;
    next.src = offersRing.nextElement().url;
}

document.getElementById("leftnav").addEventListener("click", function () {
    offersRing.increment(-1);
    update();
}, false);

document.getElementById("rightnav").addEventListener("click", function () {
    offersRing.increment(1);
    update();
}, false);

update();
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4mzeA/)

Comment: that is almost perfect--save I need the right thumbnail too--maybe I can figure it out by fiddling with your code--I also need to change the text being displayed--I realize I only have the price and hotel name for one hotel being displayed now, but can I ask you to add that to your fiddle? ...Thanks!!!!--Yvette

Comment: My example has the correct thumbnail. The same image is used for both `large` and `thumb` just scaled with CSS. You really need to make more effort with being clear in your question, be specific, add and tidy your code, provide a jsFiddle. Try read http://stackoverflow.com/help it has much advice about asking questions.

Comment: I know your thumbnail is correct but I need two..as that is the way the ad is designed...The way I added the second is by adding 1 to the array, so it would show the next image in the array which lead to all those problems...I'm sorry I haven't been clear and tried to make a jsFiddle but couldn't get the images to display

Comment: Just add a second `buffer` (or however many you need) of the same length as the first with the pictures that you want, then use the same `currentPosition` to index them. I don't have the time to add a second `buffer` of alternatives to the example.

Comment: they would be the same images--the problem is because I am adding 1 to the thumb on the right I had to put in an if then statement to reset it if it exceeded the array length...

Comment: Well as you can see in my example, with `normaliseCurrentPosition` you don't need to worry, just limit to a `uint32` and `mod` by the `bufferLength`.

Comment: I'm sorry that is over my head:(what is unsigned int 32?

Comment: I added the second thumb but could use a little help doing what you suggested----http://jsfiddle.net/yvillicana/cV9Y4/

Comment: It is a number from `0` to `2^32-1`, see [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#>>>_(Zero-fill_right_shift) and `%` === `mod` or `modulus`, see [Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators)

Comment: You can't just do `currentPosition+1`, you have to use the same principle that I just described. Create a `normaliseNextPosition`

Comment: Thanks so much--I'm trying to figure it out--will post what I achieved soon

Comment: well, didn't get as far as I hoped --can't get my thumbs to show up and the navs doesnt work--http://jsfiddle.net/yvillicana/cV9Y4/3/

Comment: Why do you have HTML in the buffer strings? They should just be the full URLs to the images, just like in my example.

Comment: this is what I came up with and it does work but not on jsFiddle--don't know why--Perhaps, because I have separate <script> tags around the end where it starts with var goleft--Ideally, I'd like to have the images scroll and saw some exs that used css3 and js, but I couldn't get it working...http://jsfiddle.net/yvillicana/cV9Y4/13/

Comment: See my update for a working example of your code based on my example code.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much...                                      ---Yvette