# How to make back and next buttons for images and/or videos in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I'm trying to make back and next buttons for, in this case, an iframe. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var array=["npvNPORFXpc", "CcsUYu0PVxY", "dE_XVl7fwBQ", "iIwxR6kjTfA", "USe6s2kfuWk"];
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    var previousRandom = "npvNPORFXpc"; // initial video
    document.getElementById('random').addEventListener('click', function () {
        do {
            var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        } 
        while (previousRandom === random)
        var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+random;
        previousRandom = random;
        iframe.src = url;
    });
</script>
```

With a bit of HTML:

```
<button id="random">Random</button><br>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/npvNPORFXpc" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So I want to create two buttons, one for going to the next video in the var array and a second for the previous video in the var array.

I just started with JS and couldn't find an example that I understood.
Should have started with the basics of JS instead of this project, but still would like to finish this!

http://jsfiddle.net/MPNU2/

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089936/having-trouble-with-circular-array-and-large-image-displayed/22091185#22091185

Comment: You'll have to store the current index of the array - then when you hit next or previous you increment or decrement the index. You also have to check to see if there is a next or previous video

Comment: Could you give me a more specific example this helps and do understand a bit, i know what i need the script to do. Like u say i have to indicate the current array the previous and the next. So when the current "video" is active it must know what was the previous or what is next. Just dont know how to write this in javascript

Comment: Did you look at the example that I pointed you at?

Comment: `Should have started with the basics of JS instead of this project`, You should always learn the basic while working with a new language. If you do it before or during is irrelevant but if you are not learning them at all you find yourself copy-pasting solutions you don't understand and cannot maintain/support. The [**JavaScript MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a good resource, [**CodeAcademy-JavaScript**](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) is nice and [**CodeWars**](http://www.codewars.com/) is cool too. Lots of resource there.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and the info i will definantly look into that! I know i started on the wrong foot, going back to the start now. I will be using this as things will get more clear while learning js.

Answer (score 1):

Example using the example that I pointed you at.

CSS

```
#utubeFrame {
    display:block;
    width:640px;
    height:360px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="random">Random</button>
<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<iframe id="utubeFrame"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
function RingArray(object, position) {
    this.array = RingArray.compact(object);
    this.setPosition(position);
}

RingArray.toInt32 = function (number) {
    return number >> 0;
};

RingArray.toUint32 = function (number) {
    return number >>> 0;
};

RingArray.isOdd = function (number) {
    return number % 2 === 1;
};

RingArray.indexWrap = function (index, length) {
    index = RingArray.toInt32(index);
    length = RingArray.toUint32(length);
    if (index < 0 && RingArray.isOdd(length)) {
        index -= 1;
    }

    return RingArray.toUint32(index) % length;
};

RingArray.compact = (function (filter) {
    var compact;

    if (typeof filter === 'function') {
        compact = function (object) {
            return filter.call(object, function (element) {
                return element;
            });
        };
    } else {
        compact = function (object) {
            object = Object(object);
            var array = [],
                length = RingArray.toUint32(object.length),
                index;

            for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
                if (index in object) {
                    array.push(object[index]);
                }
            }

            return array;
        };
    }

    return compact;
}(Array.prototype.filter));

RingArray.prototype = {
    setPosition: function (position) {
        this.position = RingArray.indexWrap(position, this.array.length);

        return this;
    },

    setToStart: function () {
        return this.setPosition(0);
    },

    setToEnd: function () {
        return this.setPosition(this.array.length - 1);
    },

    setRandom: function () {
        return this.setPosition(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array.length));
    },

    increment: function (amount) {
        return this.setPosition(this.position + (RingArray.toInt32(amount) || 1));
    },

    previousElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position - 1, this.array.length)];
    },

    currentElement: function () {
        return this.array[this.position];
    },

    nextElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position + 1, this.array.length)];
    }
};

var utubeFrame = document.getElementById('utubeFrame'),
    utubeIds = ["npvNPORFXpc", "CcsUYu0PVxY", "dE_XVl7fwBQ", "iIwxR6kjTfA", "USe6s2kfuWk"],
    baseURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/',
    utubeRing = new RingArray(utubeIds);

function update() {
    utubeFrame.src = baseURL + utubeRing.currentElement();
}

document.getElementById('random').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var currentElement = utubeRing.currentElement();

    do {
        utubeRing.setRandom();
    } while (utubeRing.currentElement() === currentElement);
    update();
});

document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener("click", function () {
    utubeRing.increment(-1);
    update();
}, false);

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function () {
    utubeRing.increment(1);
    update();
}, false);

update();
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/TWvvD/)

Comment: Thanks this helps aswell! I see that in this case the video is already in the js. Does look a lil more complicated for now. I did remove the html of the frame and styled it in CSS! :). I will compare ur script with the other examples given to see what it does different. but first i should really need to learn some more about js. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="random">Random</button>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<button id="prevVideo">Prev</button>
<button id="nextVideo">Next</button><br>

<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/npvNPORFXpc" width="640"      height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var array=["npvNPORFXpc", "CcsUYu0PVxY", "dE_XVl7fwBQ", "iIwxR6kjTfA", "USe6s2kfuWk"];
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
var previousRandom = "npvNPORFXpc"; // initial video
document.getElementById('random').addEventListener('click', function () {
do {
    var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
} while (previousRandom === random)
var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+random;
previousRandom = random;
iframe.src = url;});

document.getElementById('prevVideo').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var curIndex = array.indexOf(previousRandom);
    curIndex--;
    if (curIndex < 0)
    {
        curIndex = array.length -1;
    }
    var video = array[curIndex];
    var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video;
    previousRandom = video;
    iframe.src = url;
});

document.getElementById('nextVideo').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var curIndex = array.indexOf(previousRandom);
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex >= array.length)
    {
        curIndex = 0;
    }
    var video = array[curIndex];
    var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video;
    previousRandom = video;
    iframe.src = url;
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/z47XP/

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i ment! Would you like to explain a little bit more of whats happening? (copy and paste does teach alot but..:p).

Comment: When the "nextVideo" button is clicked, first of all you have to find the index of the current video:
`var curIndex = array.indexOf(previousRandom);`
(first video->index=0, second video->index=1, and so on...)
Then you can calculate the next video index:
`curIndex++;`
Since there is a limited number of videos (in your case 5), you have to be sure to not load the 6th video :-)
`if (curIndex >= array.length) { curIndex = 0; }`
And finally, you can convert the video index to url:
`var video = array[curIndex];
var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video;
previousRandom = video;
iframe.src = url`

Comment: Thanks again this makes me understand js and the working of js alot more! But i should start at the basics as i didn't do i just went for my idea :P thanks for helping it work, now im going back to the start to really learn it :) and ofcourse ill be using this hehe!