# jquery store urls into an array and open them using .click(); function with controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

My Exlanation of what I am trying to do, (tried explaining it in 2 ways to help you get an idea)

example 1

1. store all elements like so:  `<a href="etc">url1</a>` from inside `<div class=".resources"></div>` in an array, so that they could be clicked with  `click();`  function
2. open first url from array with  **default**  button - i.e. `$(array[0]).click();`
3. open next url from array with   **next**   button - i.e. last clicked `$(array[+1]).click();`
4. open previous url from array with   **prev**   button - i.e. last clicked `$(array[-1]).click();`

example 2

1. create an empty class in **HTML** like so: `<div class="resources"></div>`
2. create an array of URLs in **JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY** and store them within **.resources** class
3. create  **prev** ,  **default** ,  **next**  buttons in **HTML**
4. **default**  button when clicked opens first URL from array i.e.: `$(array[0]).click();`
5. **next**  button when clicked opens next URL from array i.e.: `$(array[+1]).click();`
6. **prev**  button when clicked opens previous URL from array i.e.: `$(array[-1]).click();`

**MUSTS:**
urls must be opened with: `click();` function: like so:  `$(array[0]).click();`

**fiddle** to make it clearer: [view fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kred2yb/)

Comment: So, what is the problem that you are having then?

Comment: i am having problem bringing it to reality, literally spent the past 8 hours trying to make it work and can't

Comment: `array[-1]` wont work as array's do not have a negative index, you would need to keep a index variable and manipulate that

Comment: So basically you don't know how to code a ring or circular buffer in javascript? Here is one example but there are other references here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174549/how-to-make-back-and-next-buttons-for-images-and-or-videos-in-javascript/22175919#22175919

Comment: ya that's what I am aiming to do, but not with videos, rather with URLs. I am using a soundcloud api, which takes a link and plays it when it's clicked. that's why I posted the above example with of what I am aiming for with URLs. All the URLs must be stored within .resources class, and when they're clicked audio is played. Rather then having all URLs shown, I want to have just buttons showing, which would go to next url, if that makes sense

Comment: The `RingArray` constructor that I pointed you at can handle any array-like object, so just create a new object using the result of your query and set your click handlers appropriately, using the methods provided by `RingArray`.

Comment: will try, gonna report back in an hour or so

Comment: what your code does is insert a src attribute into the iframe. Whereas, I am trying to add this: <a href="url"></a> inside .resources div. I have no success after 2 hours of trying

Comment: I know what that examples ancillary code does, but that is not part of the constructor `RingArray`. It should take about <5 minutes to use `RingArray` with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show show you how simple it is to impliment `RingArray` for use with your code example.

CSS

```
body {
    color: #fff;
}
.link {
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="resources">
    <a href="url1"></a>  
    <a href="url2"></a>  
    <a href="url3"></a>  
    <a href="url4"></a>    
</div>

/* index -= 1 */
<div class="link open-prev">click previous link</div> 
/* indexed [0] */
<div class="link open-current-link">click default link</div> 
/* index += 1 */
<div class="link open-next">click next link</div>
```

Javascript

```
function RingArray(object, position) {
    this.array = RingArray.compact(object);
    this.setPosition(position);
}

RingArray.toInt32 = function (number) {
    return number >> 0;
};

RingArray.toUint32 = function (number) {
    return number >>> 0;
};

RingArray.isOdd = function (number) {
    return number % 2 === 1;
};

RingArray.indexWrap = function (index, length) {
    index = RingArray.toInt32(index);
    length = RingArray.toUint32(length);
    if (index < 0 && RingArray.isOdd(length)) {
        index -= 1;
    }

    return RingArray.toUint32(index) % length;
};

RingArray.compact = (function (filter) {
    var compact;

    if (typeof filter === 'function') {
        compact = function (object) {
            return filter.call(object, function (element) {
                return element;
            });
        };
    } else {
        compact = function (object) {
            object = Object(object);
            var array = [],
                length = RingArray.toUint32(object.length),
                index;

            for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
                if (index in object) {
                    array.push(object[index]);
                }
            }

            return array;
        };
    }

    return compact;
}(Array.prototype.filter));

RingArray.prototype = {
    setPosition: function (position) {
        this.position = RingArray.indexWrap(position, this.array.length);

        return this;
    },

    setToStart: function () {
        return this.setPosition(0);
    },

    setToEnd: function () {
        return this.setPosition(this.array.length - 1);
    },

    setRandom: function () {
        return this.setPosition(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array.length));
    },

    increment: function (amount) {
        return this.setPosition(this.position + (RingArray.toInt32(amount) || 1));
    },

    previousElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position - 1, this.array.length)];
    },

    currentElement: function () {
        return this.array[this.position];
    },

    nextElement: function () {
        return this.array[RingArray.indexWrap(this.position + 1, this.array.length)];
    }
};

/* get urls and store in an array */
var links = $('.resources a[href*="url"]'),
    linkRing = new RingArray(links);

/* click and open default link ! */
$('.open-current-link').on('click', function () {
    console.log(linkRing.setToStart());
});

/* click and open next link */
$('.open-next').on('click', function () {
    console.log(linkRing.increment(1));
});

/* click and open previous link */
$('.open-prev').on('click', function () {
    console.log(linkRing.increment(-1));
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ahvrqyq5/)

Comment: when i used the console.log it logged the correct URL however, nothing else happens. I believe that it needs to be able to click the whole anchor element, because only then the song plays<a href="http://example.com class="player">song name</a> when I click this myself it only works then.

Comment: Sure, you have to add the `.click()` code to the code that I have demonstrated, I just logged the output for you to see that the `RingArray` works, you need to do something like `$(linkRing.increment(1).currentElement()).click()` or whatever you want to do with the information stored at the `currentElement`.

Comment: If you don't know how to dispatch a click event, then that's another question, and there are many examples here on SO. Here is an example using pure modern Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711051/auto-click-script-within-a-browser/24712697#24712697 But I'm sure you can also find examples using jQuery if that is what you want.

Comment: I do know, and I had it added. Just forgot to post it to this comment. I also added an alert function and the correct URL is clicked however, for some reason the song doesn't change. Check this fiddle I just made, that's what I am trying to do, but with controls 'next' 'prev' 'current' http://jsfiddle.net/zctgyf88/

Comment: I don't see a link to your current fiddle, with the `RingArray` code that I posted in my answer?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zctgyf88 this is the idea, and because when you click on a link it starts playing I thought that I could implement this URL changer and the controls would play the next song previous etc

Comment: Yes, that is the link that I went to, but I don't see any Javascript other than libraries being loaded, on that fiddle.

Comment: Well, to begin with you have changed the class in the HTML from `resources` to `post` but not changed the jQuery selector to reflect this HTML change.

Comment: You are also inluding `jquery.min.js` v1.4.2 as an external library, aswell as jQuery v1.9.1 from the menu and from the `console` it shows `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` as 1.4.1 is being loaded after 1.9.1 and doesn't have a method `on` Or so it seems

Comment: the github example uses jquery 1.4 only, however, 1.9 files are available for download and I am using them on my own machine. just don't have a cdn to upload them to fiddler: check this they're here: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player i am using: sc-player-minimal

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the time to look into the `soundcloud` API or files. What I can say is that the `RingArray` works as expected (demonstrated in my answer) and from that you can then dispatch an event on the `currentElement`. what I can say is that `soundcloud` is using the deprecated `live` method, so if you are going to use 1.4.1 then you will need to change `on` to `click` (or something like that) in your code. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xx05mn6e/6/

Comment: but if the tracks play from inside the .post class only, it should somehow be possible to control them, maybe have only one URL by default and others stored in an array and replace the value of href attribute with the controls. i.e. 'next' button puts next url from array

Comment: We are way off topic from your original problem now, which was how to implement a ring array in Javascript.

Comment: it's still on topic because we're talking about replacing URL's with URL's from an array. Which we are close to doing now. I believe that what I mentioned in prior reply would work 100%

Comment: The `RingArray` constructor will accept any array-like object, be it an object that looks like an array, a real array, a jQuery object, a DOM NodeList etc etc. What you do with the data at the current indexed `RingArray` element is up to you. So an array of URLs (strings) will be fine for the `RingArray`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sab60wff/ this fiddle works fine now, url changes with controls. however, could you alter it so that the utubeFrame is a CLASS. Then i will accept it as a solution, thanks for your time so far

Comment: Sure, change the HTML `id` to `class` and then `utubeFrame = $('.utubeframe')` and `utubeFrame[0].href = ...` instead of `utubeFrame.href = ...` should do it, I believe.

Comment: ok thanks accepted as solution, what difference does the [0] make?

Comment: so I tried this 'console.log($("a").attr("href"));' on 'random' button and it displays the same url everytime. it doesn't update it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60415/discussion-on-answer-by-xotic750-jquery-store-urls-into-an-array-and-open-them-u).

Answer (score 1):

I modified your fiddle a bit and it seems to do what you want; if I understood it correctly:

[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kred2yb/4/)

```
var links = $( '.resources a[href*="url"]' );

var currentLink = 0;

/* click and open default link ! */ 
$('.open-current-link').on('click', function(){ 
    $( links[currentLink] ).click();        
});

/* click and open next link */ 
$('.open-next').on('click', function(){  
    currentLink = currentLink + 1;
    if (currentLink == 4){
        currentLink = 0;
    }
    alert('clicking ' + $(links[currentLink]).attr('href'));
    $( links[currentLink] ).click();        
});

/* click and open previous link */
$('.open-prev').on('click', function(){
    currentLink = currentLink - 1;

    if (currentLink == -1){
        currentLink = 3;
    }

    alert('clicking ' + $(links[currentLink]).attr('href'));
    $( links[currentLink] ).click();      
});
```

Comment: You can change if (currentLink == 4) with if (currentLink == links.length)

Comment: You also need to call $(links[currentLink])[0].click()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sf2xugta/ of what I am trying to apply this to, but i cant get it to work